# How to check AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS/AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS is enabled for database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a project database that maintain different databases from different environnement (dev, test, prod, predprod...), I need to check if `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` and `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICSis` set to `OFF/ON` against each DB and if its `OFF`- alter it to `ON`.

```
ALTER DATABASE  DB
SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON

ALTER DATABASE  DB
SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses a Dynamic SQL query. It excludes system databases. Checks for `is_auto_create_stats_on` or `is_auto_update_stats_on` 0 `OFF` and change it to `ON`

```
declare @sql    nvarchar(max);

; with 
db as
(
    select  name, is_auto_create_stats_on, is_auto_update_stats_on 
    from    sys.databases
    where   name    not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
    and     (
                is_auto_create_stats_on = 0
            or  is_auto_update_stats_on = 0
            )
)
select  @sql    = isnull(@sql + char(13), '')
                + 'ALTER DATABASE ' + quotename(db.name) + ' '
                + 'SET ' + o.opt + ' ON;'
from    db 
        cross apply
        (
            select  opt = 'AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS'
            where   is_auto_create_stats_on = 0

            union all

            select  opt = 'AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS'
            where   is_auto_update_stats_on = 0
        ) o

-- print out for verification before execute
print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

You may mask the `sp_executesql` and verify the result before actual execution

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

-- getting the commands list
SET @SQL = (
    SELECT '' + x.cmd
    FROM (
        select 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;' AS cmd
        from sys.databases
        WHERE database_id > 4
            AND is_auto_create_stats_on = 0
        UNION ALL
        select 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON;'
        from sys.databases
        WHERE database_id > 4
            AND is_auto_update_stats_on = 0
    ) x
    FOR XML PATH('')
);

IF @SQL IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL;

--uncomment to execute
--  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
END
```